# Sum 1:n by group

Tags: r

Have: Dataset I need to sum i:n for each row within each group

```
demo<-data.frame(th=c(c(0,24,26),(c(0,1,2,4))),hs=c(rep(220,3),c(rep(240,4))),
    seq=(c(1:3,1:4)),group=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,4)))
```

Here's what that looks like:

```
> demo
  th  hs seq group
1  0 220   1     1
2 24 220   2     1
3 26 220   3     1
4  0 240   1     2
5  1 240   2     2
6  2 240   3     2
7  4 240   4     2
```

Need a vector that is a based on the `hs`, `seq`, and `th` columns but that is a summation of the `hs` column raised to the `seq` column and times the `th` columns up to that row within the `group`.

```
demo[1,"an"]<-    demo[1,"hs"]^demo[1,"seq"] * demo[1,"th"]
demo[2,"an"]<-sum(demo[1,"hs"]^demo[1,"seq"] * demo[1,"th"],
                                     demo[2,"hs"]^demo[2,"seq"] * demo[2,"th"] )
demo[3,"an"]<-sum(demo[1,"hs"]^demo[1,"seq"] * demo[1,"th"],
                                     demo[2,"hs"]^demo[2,"seq"] * demo[2,"th"],
                                        demo[3,"hs"]^demo[3,"seq"] * demo[3,"th"])

demo[6,"an"]<-sum(demo[4,"hs"]^demo[4,"seq"] * demo[4,"th"],
                                     demo[5,"hs"]^demo[5,"seq"] * demo[5,"th"],
                                        demo[6,"hs"]^demo[6,"seq"] * demo[6,"th"])
```

Here's what that new column (`an`) should look like

```
> demo
  th  hs seq group        an
1  0 220   1     1         0
2 24 220   2     1   1161600
3 26 220   3     1 278009600
4  0 240   1     2        NA
5  1 240   2     2        NA
6  2 240   3     2  27705600
7  4 240   4     2        NA
```

Ignore the NA's in this MRE, those need to be filled in too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Libraries

```
 library(tidyverse)
```

### Sample data

```
df <-
   read.csv(
      text = 
 "th hs seq group
0 220 1 1
24 220 2 1
26 220 3 1
0 240 1 2
1 240 2 2
2 240 3 2
4 240 4 2",
sep = " ",header = T
 )
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
   #Grouping by group
   group_by(group) %>%
   #Applying a cumulative sum of the formula, by group
   mutate(an = cumsum(hs^seq*th))
```

### Output

```
     th    hs   seq group          an
  <int> <int> <int> <int>       <dbl>
1     0   220     1     1           0
2    24   220     2     1     1161600
3    26   220     3     1   278009600
4     0   240     1     2           0
5     1   240     2     2       57600
6     2   240     3     2    27705600
7     4   240     4     2 13298745600
```

Comment: I think the TO wants this to be grouped by group, so you might want to add a `group_by`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, an := cumsum(hs^seq^th), group]
```